# How to skip number of lines that changed in run time in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, delete-file, skip

I have many folders and i need to delete from any folder the oldest files in it, the number of files that i need to delete changed any iteration so i tried to do a for loop that in any iteration do date sort, after the oldest file at the top of the file i do "skip=variable" this variable changed any iteration and it's not work.

Is someone have any idea how to solve it in batch file? 
Thanks!

Comment: We will need a bit of code to help you. Thanks

Comment: So you append "skip=variable" to the files you want to skip and it isn't skipping them?  Is that the issue?

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%i in ( C:\folder\varibales_file.txt ) do (set numOfFiles=%%j & pushd %%i & ( for /f "skip=numOfFiles " %%F in ('dir C:\folder_path_to_delete\%%i /b /o-d') do ( rd /s /q C:\folder_path_to_delete\%%i\%%F))&popd)

Comment: the error is: "  " was unexpected at this time."

Comment: `for /f "skip=numOfFiles " `should be `for /f "skip=!numOfFiles!" ` (and you'd need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: hi Stephan thanks, i try it too, when i do it there is an error "The system cannot find the file "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options of `for /F` command (`"skip... delims... tokens"`, etc) can *not* be changed after the `for /F` command was parsed. You need to change the value of `"skip=!numOfFiles!"` in a different subroutine, so the `for /F` command be parsed each time it is executed:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%i in ( C:\folder\varibales_file.txt ) do (
   set numOfFiles=%%j
   pushd %%i
   call :Sub !numOfFiles!
   popd
)
goto :EOF


:Sub numOfFiles
for /f "skip=%1 delims=" %%F in ('dir "C:\folder_path_to_delete\%%i" /b /o-d') do (
   rd /s /q "C:\folder_path_to_delete\%%i\%%F"
)
```

Comment: hi,thanks for your answer, i tried what you said, but it's not work, i got an error: "The system on the command is incorrect"

 here is the code:

@echo off

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

net use \\haifa-nas\build_results\CleanupLogs\reut_cleanup
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%i in ( C:\folder\varibales_file.txt)
 do ( set numOfBuild=%%j 
 pushd %%i 
 call :Sub !numOfBuild!
 popd
 
 )
 
 goto :EOF
 
 :sub numOfBuild

   for /f "skip=%1 delims=" %%F in
 ('dir C:\folder_path_to_delete\%%i /b /o-d') 
 do ( rd /s /q C:\folder_path_to_delete\%%i\%%F )

Comment: i've sent it in a few lines but it's appears as one line

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand you... You must insert my code in a .BAT file and then execute the file!

Comment: ok i've had a problem with a spesific folder, now it's work :)
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I did the following changes to your "one-line-code":

- reformatting into a proper and readable batchfile
- using `numOfOFiles` as delayed variable (you did it as a string which couldn't work)
- enclosed all paths/filenames in quotes to proper work with spaces in direcotries or filenames
- added `delims=` for the same reason
- remove `ECHO` if the output satisfies you.

(corected code only, didn't check if it does, what you want)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%i in (C:\folder\varibales_file.txt) do (
  set numOfFiles=%%j
  pushd %%i 
  for /f "skip=!numOfFiles! delims=" %%F in ('dir "C:\folder_path_to_delete\%%i" /b /o-d') do (
    ECHO rd /s /q "C:\folder_path_to_delete\%%i\%%F"
  popd
)
```

are you sure, you want to use `rd` (Remove Directory), not `del` (DELete file)?

Comment: Thanks,i tried it and there is an error  "The system cannot find the file ..." although the file exist